# Migrating a Rails application that uses Active Record to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, rails-activerecord, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have written a Rails (5.2) application that uses the default Active Record ORM, and Devise for authenticating users. It has a few other models and associations:

- User has_one Card
- User has_many Subscriptions
- Subscription has_many Invoices
- ....

Now, I have to switch to MongoDB, all articles I've found on the net are about using MongoDB instead of a relational database from the scratch, and, of course, I don't want to rewrite everything from scratch.

From what I've understood, here are steps that I have to follow in order to migrate from Active Record to MongoDB, using, for example, the mongoid gem:

1. Remove all `< ActiveRecord::Base` inheritances
2. Include `Mongoid::Document` in model classes
3. Translate each line of `db/schema.rb` into a line in the molde class, for example:

   `t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false` in `db/schema.rb`

   to

   `field :encrypted_password, type: String, default: "", null: false` in `MyModel` class
4. Configure Rspec to use mongoid `config.include Mongoid::Matchers`
5. Configure `database_cleaner` to use mongoid `DatabaseCleaner.orm = 'mongoid'`
6. Run `rails generate mongoid:config`
7. Replace `require 'devise/orm/active_record'` by `require 'devise/orm/mongoid'` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

There are still some open questions likes:

- Do I have to translate also `created_at` and `updated_at`? (my guess is "yes")
- Do models validations still valid? Or do I have to adapt them?
- Is there any other step I have forgotten?
- Is there any ready-to-use solution?

Comment: I think you talk about MongoDB, not MangoDB

Comment: yes, thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1):

as of Ruby 3.3 and Rails 7.x -- MongoDB now how an official tutorial [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongoid/current/tutorials/getting-started-rails7/#existing-application)